# Could cancel/delete trigger VsCode intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I want to trigger completions when I delete a character in VsCode. How should I do?

I tried `del` character (ASCII 127), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense), you can accomplish this by using `Ctrl+Space` for that, or any autocomplete triggering characters.

> You can trigger IntelliSense in any editor window by typing Ctrl+Space
>   or by typing a trigger character (such as the dot character (.) in
>   JavaScript).

Comment: Yes, it's useful. But I still expect the delete key to trigger completion.

Comment: That is a nice feature, but i don't think it's still implemented. Maybe you should [open an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)

Comment: the issue is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87029) and it's invalid by design.